# Token cookie is still in request header after deleting from Safari browser

Tags: cookies, next.js, axios, safari, react-query

I have a NextJS app using ReactQuery (TanStack) and axios, which uses a "token" Cookie for authentication with a backend server (Spring Boot).

**The cookie has somehow been deleted from the storage in the browser (Safari), but when I perform the request again, the cookie is still included in the request.**

The cookie has a 1 year expiration time.

This has previously happened in Chrome too, although I'm not sure how to reproduce the error.

What could be the cause of this? Some sort of cache header, browser bug, or something else?